# Modeling Derived Feature vs Original Features

Tags: regression, time-series, predictive-models, arima

I have a very simple time series dataset with three features. And I created a fourth feature with the following formula:

Var4 = ((Var1 + Var2)/Var3)

I created three ARIMA models to predict the three original variables and used the predicted values to calculate a prediction for Var 4 with the above formula.

I then found my self wondering if I shouldn’t just have created an ARIMA model on Var4 directly and predict its values.

Are there any theoretical reasons why one option would be better than the other? Or should I just look at RMSE and pick the best model?